# Hidden notification bar reappearing after screen lock and unlock

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I hid my notification bar for my activity by changing the theme to

```
Theme.NoTitlebar.FullScreen and then changed it in my manifest too.
```

I successfully hid the notification bar. But if I lock and then again unlock the screen when in the same activity, the notification bar becomes visible. How do I overcome this?
I want to hide my notification bar throughout my activity.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when I use TabHost. Here are a workaround for this problem:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    if (hasFocus) {
        getWindow().getDecorView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            }
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

This is drawn first with the notification bar and redrawn after the ms.

The best solution, if you don't use TabHost.