# Notification Bar visibility

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

My application is running landscape mode and I have set the following property of activity in manifest file

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

It surely hides the notification bar when my activity is running. But when for suppose I launch browser activity from my app and returns, the notification bar is visible again. I am trying to find its solution nothing is working. I followed the following link but in vain. 
[Hidden notification bar reappearing after screen lock and unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8443809/hidden-notification-bar-reappearing-after-screen-lock-and-unlock)
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I handle these things in my java code

```
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
```

The nice part of handling this in java is you can release those flags at any time to get rid of full screen. I put this before setContent but I can't recall if that it required or not.

If this doesn't keep it fullscreen you could try to put it in the onResume(), which is my guess how your losing it.